# How to use AngularJS ng-repeat on <ul> tag without repeating it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

With this code:

```
<ul data-ng-repeat="airport in airports">
            <li>{{airport.code}}</li>
            <li>{{airport.city}}</li>
            <li>{{airport.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I end up with **three** `<ul>`, each with **one** `<li>` inside of them.

How can I get **one** `<ul>` with **three** `<li>` inside?

Comment: It's perfectly clearn isn't it? He wants to repeat what is inside the ul, not the ul itself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [ng-repeat-start directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="airport in airports">{{airport.code}}</li>
    <li>{{airport.city}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat-end>{{airport.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here it is working in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QMpMCVK9iE3WVkIXWsRj?p=preview).

Comment: It should be noted that this only works in the 1.2 release candidate, before this ng-repeat-start does not exist.

Comment: Thanks!
I have tried repeat-start and end, it did not work, but I will try again

Comment: Thanks Erik, i Followed a tutorial, and the source code used a older version of angular.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this type:

```html
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='i in [1,2,3]'>{{i}}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used ng-repaet as:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="rp in $ctrl.repeat">{{rp}}</li>
</ul>
```

**{{rp}}** repeat object x time

**Output should like this:**

> .list 1
>
> .list 2
>
> .list 3